# Port foward to Server that has different gateway

Tags: port-forwarding, sonicwall

We have two ISPS (2 gateways  one Sonicwall and one Verizon Router) and one internal LAN.

The sonicwall internal IP is 192.168.1.1 and verizon is 192.168.1.2

On the sonicwall I configured a port forward for RDP to go to an internal server on the same 192.168.1 network. However, this server is using the Verizon router as a gateway.

When I tested it out, it doesnt work. I guess i'm trying to understand why it doesnt work. if the Sonicwall can ping the internal Server's IP, why can't it forward to this Server? Why does the Server HAVE to use the sonicwall as a gateway for this RDP to work?

Comment: Because routing happens at layer 3. When the Sonicwall forwards the traffic to the server, the server sees that the source ip address is not local and attempts to communicate with the source via its default gateway, which is the Verizon router.

Comment: I'd use an ssh tunnel or a UDP proxy to work around this.

Answer (score 0):

you could try to add a static route on the RDP server (that server that has a default gateway to verizon / 192.168.1.2).  the static route would look like:

> $remote_rdp_client_public_ip/32 via 192.168.1.1